# hex string to character in python

Tags: python, hex

I have a hex string like:

```
data = "437c2123"
```

I want to convert this string to a sequence of characters according to the ASCII table.
The result should be like:

```
data_con = "C|!#"
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Why are you quoting C code, if this is a Python question? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Which type of python is this? :D

Comment: After your edit it is better, you guys can stop the close votes.

Comment: Oh well then it is still undecided if he really wants python or not, we may never know.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
In [17]: data = "437c2123"

In [18]: ''.join(chr(int(data[i:i+2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(data), 2))
Out[18]: 'C|!#'
```

Here:

- `for i in range(0, len(data), 2)` iterates over every second position in `data`: `0`, `2`, `4` etc.
- `data[i:i+2]` looks at every pair of hex digits `'43'`, `'7c'`, etc.
- `chr(int(..., 16))` converts the pair of hex digits into the corresponding character.
- `''.join(...)` merges the characters into a single string.

Comment: if data = "aabbccdd", i mean the convertion of hex is ascii invisible, what should i do? can it stock the right characters? i don't need to print the string, but i hope it can stock the right values. thank u

Answer (score 38):

In Python2

```
>>> "437c2123".decode('hex')
'C|!#'
```

In Python3 (also works in Python2, for <2.6 you can't have the `b` prefixing the string)

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify(b"437c2123")
b'C|!#'
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Python 2.6 you can use simple:

```
data_con = bytes.fromhex(data)
```

Answer (score -3):

The `ord` function converts characters to numerical values and the `chr` function does the inverse. So to convert `97` to `"a"`, do `ord(97)`

Comment: `False` and your answer does not cover enough to be considered an answer. `ord` does not take an integer parameter.